# Can I force the browser to rasterize elements before they become visible?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, google-chrome, firefox

Call me crazy, but I'm working on a game using vanilla DOM and TypeScript. It's not action-heavy, but there are some animations going on, which are driven from JavaScript (too complex to do in CSS).

I'm already applying [the common trick of `translateZ(0)`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/stick-to-compositor-only-properties-and-manage-layer-count) (called [null transform hack](https://aerotwist.com/blog/on-translate3d-and-layer-creation-hacks/) or less accurately [silver bullet](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/optimization-and-performance/)) to pull animated elements into their own rendering layer, and I'm animating nothing besides compositor-only properties (`transform` and `opacity`). This works beautifully: during the game, everything feels buttery smooth, even on older mobile devices.

The problem is during the start of the game. At that moment, about 70 individually transformed and animated elements enter the page one by one over the space of a few seconds, by animating their `opacity` from 0 to nonzero. This is causing visible stutter during the animation.

My guess was that Chrome is being too clever here, and will only rasterize each element at the moment it first becomes visible. A quick check with the dev tools confirms this, as there's a lot of rasterization going on even during the animation:

[image: Lots of "Rasterize Paint" going on]

I would prefer to rasterize all these elements once, before the animation starts, and only then trigger the animation. But how can I force rasterization of elements that aren't yet visible, without showing a flash of them to the user?

I'd be happy with a Chrome-only approach, but cross-browser would be even better.

Comment: Did you try to render the elements outside of the view scope of the client? You could "pre-render" the elements, hide them and then move them to the desired staring point. Another extra cheap solution would be an overlay that hides the rendition phase until all elements have the desired state.

Comment: I didn't try moving them outside the viewport. Was hoping this was a solved problem before I dive in too deeply (in which case I'll of course post an answer myself). An overlay might work in this case!

Comment: Moving elements outside the viewport using something like `translate(-9999px, -9999px)` doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: So, when you remove the opacity transition and start your app there is no delay or lag noticeable? While re-reading your question it seems that only at the start of the game all elements are transitioned at once. While the game runs individual elements are being transitioned at a certain time. So maybe the actual problem is in fact the multiple, simultaneous transitions of "too many" elements. This behaviour should be reproducable in a simple demo. 
Maybe for your use case it would be more applicable to add an opacity transition to the app-body instead on single elements at the beginning.

Comment: @NicoO No, the elements are transitioned (faded in) one by one, not all at the same time. Otherwise we'd have only one slow frame at the start, which would hardly be noticeable.

Comment: Sorry, that is in fact what you have written in your question before. I tried to somewhat replicate your problem, writing a silly demo app: https://jsfiddle.net/b3vjwuny/ But i guess this is a bad comparison of what is actually going on ... Maybe you can use it to showcase the problem.

Comment: @NicoO Thanks for the fiddle! I updated it to be more representative, with more expensive rasterization and per-element transforms: https://jsfiddle.net/4q36ufLb/3/ It's a bit choppy, but what most surprises me is that there is very little rasterization going on -- or indeed very little of anything. And yet it's not smooth.

Comment: The experience will be difference across machines, according to their specs. At least in the fiddle I can not find the massive rasterization blocks from your screenshot. But maybe I just looked in the wrong place.

Comment: I realized something silly: I'd been rendering most of the elements at 2.5x their displayed size, then scaling them down. That caused the massive rasterization blocks. However, now that I'm rid of those, it's still not smooth, just like in the fiddle.